# Search a list of terms from google using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have followed this SO question [Searching in Google with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635419/searching-in-google-with-python) and executed as explained in answer no. 2.
I used pip install Google-Search-API, then executed following code:

from google import google
    num_page = 3
    search_results = google.search("Agriculture", num_page)

But even after successfully installing the API, I am getting the import error
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this [`google` module](https://github.com/MarioVilas/google). More about it, [here](https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/)

Comment: After installing this module also, I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The code that I posted in the question works fine with python 3.