# Search program that filters results

Tags: python

Running on python 3.6 , mac OS X El Capitan , idle.

I basically want to search a title of a game on google or another search engine and I want to set a time to search it.
I've tried the code below and sometimes the code gets executed (it will open the browser and type what I want it to type) and sometimes it doesn't. 
This is my program thus far;

```
#!/Users etc
import re,sys,os.path,pip,os.path
import webbrowser

def press_key(key):
    cmd = "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" + key + "\"'"
    os.system(cmd)

b=webbrowser.get('safari')
b.open('google.com') and press_key("hello")
```

Also I want to search results in a cvs file or similar type file where i'm able to sort it "graph style". Filter results by price etc.

At this moment , what i've written down is just a script and it doesn't work all the time. 
Are there any modules to type interactively you would recommend for a mac user? I would like to look at faster alternative ways if there are any.

Comment: Sending keystrokes to an application is almost always a poor way to automate it.

Comment: if you have a better idea I would love to hear it

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38635419/4996248 There is a massive amount of material on web-scraping in Python. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not trying to sir just trying to find the best and fastest way to do the task , ty for the link will check it out